# How can I view my log files via ssh?

Tags: 7, ssh

I currently cannot access `http://example.com/admin/reports/dblog` as I cannot authenticate as an admin as my page is getting a 500 error.

I wonder if there is an actual location on my production server where Drupal errors are logged.

Answer (score 3):

If you have drush set up, you can use `drush watchdog-list` to look at the items logged to watchdog.

If you don't have access to drush, but your DB is up and running fine, you can always query the watchdog table with `Select * from watchdog;`

From personal experience, you might want to check your apache error logs as well to see if those hold anything that can help.